# Are FindBugs and SpotBugs bug descriptions compatible?

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs, spotbugs

## What I'm trying to do

I am trying to export **FindBugs** rules from **SonarQube(7.9.1)** Quality Profile and use them in **SpotBugs** locally. I would like to have the same rules in SonarQube server and in SpotBugs locally.
I exported static analysis rules using FindBugs exporter from SonarQube. Then I used created xml in SpotBugs on my machine:

```xml
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Bug pattern="SA_LOCAL_SELF_COMPARISON"/>
  </Match>
  <Match>
    <Bug pattern="UG_SYNC_SET_UNSYNC_GET"/>
  </Match>
  <Match>
    <Bug pattern="IC_SUPERCLASS_USES_SUBCLASS_DURING_INITIALIZATION"/>
  </Match>
  <!-- Other rules -->
</FindBugsFilter>
```

## Issue

**Reported bugs are different in Sonar and SpotBugs.** In SpotBugs some rules are missing. Is it possible that some bug patterns are not recognized by SpotBug, because they are FindBugs patterns?
I found bud descriptions for FindBugs and SpotBugs. Mostly they are overlapping, but there are some bugs that are only in the former or the latter:
[SpotBugs Bug Descriptions](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bugDescriptions.html)
[FindBugs Bug Descriptions](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html)

## Question

Do all bug descriptions used in FindBugs filters works in SpotBugs?

Comment: Maybe [this SpotBug issue](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs.github.io/issues/24) may help you to investigate further.